# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError - After migration from Angular 2 to 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a model driven form and a field of which is updated from code behind/typescript file on button click event. This was working fine in Angular 2. But after I migrated to Angular 4, I am getting the below exception on update,

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked.

Here is the code where I am updating the form value,

```
this.myForm.controls['myFormArray'].value['results'] = this.Results;
```

*where this.Results is an array of computed result to be shown in form.*

If I add the ChangeDetectionStratergy to OnPush in the component, then the update works fine. But I don't know the root cause of this issue, especially after upgrading to Angular 4.

Comment: You will find answers in [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) article

Comment: The check for changed expressions has become a lot stricter lately. To see where you went 'wrong', you should provide some code

Comment: @PierreDuc I have a line of code where I am trying to update.

Comment: @smhnkmr We need more information. Plunker ideally

Comment: @Maximus Yes Maxim, I have referred your article earlier and it has nice explanation on the error. But the thing, I am more interested to know why its happening in Angular 4 and not in 2?

Comment: @smhnkmr, we need a plunker